# How do I delete a UILocalNotification within a UITableViewController cell?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

My problem is that when ever I try to delete a cell from the TableView. It always seems to crash. The problem is because it can't delete a `UILocalNotification`, it doesn't know where to delete it from. It seems like i need a way to assign integers to each `UILocalNotification` or something rather. I haven't tried that yet because i don't know how to.

This is how I use the UILocalNotifications:

```
-(IBAction)threehour:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *remind = [defaults objectForKey:@"remind"];

NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10800];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = alertTime;
localNotification.alertBody = remind;
localNotification.soundName =@"alarm.mp3";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AlarmTimeBack" sender:sender];
}
```

And this is my Table View code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Get list of local notifications
        NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Display notification info
        [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)reloadTable
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

        return YES;

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }   
        else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }

        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    // Swipe ot delete action.
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
          if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:self];
        }
    }

@end
```

Comment: How about using cancelLocalNotification:. Doesn't that update the scheduledLocalNotifications array?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, when it saves it as an array.

Comment: What are the two "its" in your comment?

Comment: The answer you accepted is using the same method that I suggested, and that you said didn't work.

Comment: The other one is more simple to understand. But your answer was great too. Sorry for an inconvenience as I am new to Objective C. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code like this it would help i think...

```
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
 {
     // Delete the row from the data source

     NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  scheduledLocalNotifications];
     UILocalNotification *notify = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notify];             
     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
```

Comment: It then gives me: 
[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11410
 5   Quick Reminders                     0x0000000100004bdc -[GeneralTableViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 220
 6   UIKit                               0x000000010071ee45 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 85
 7   UIKit                               0x00000001008700b8 -[UITableViewCell _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 60
 8   UIKit                               0x0000000100653096 -

Comment: Working or still crashing?

Comment: The delete button is clickable but the app doesn't crash and it doesn't delete. once I place the endUpdates it gives me this: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't recognise "removeObjectsAtIndex". It says no visible @Interface for NSArray.

Comment: Your data source should be mutable array so only you can delete the notification.

Comment: Yes you should have delete the particular notification from shard notification array by cancelLocalNotificationMethod then update the tableview

Comment: Given the same code how do I make the "cell.detailLabelText" to show the time that is selected. Currently it just shows a random timezone.

Comment: Random time zone means? I think it shows the timezone from ur device. You can modify the time zone by Settings->General->Date& time->Timezone

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myIDToCancel = @"some_id_to_cancel";
UILocalNotification *notificationToCancel=nil;
for(UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
  if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:myIDToCancel]) {
     notificationToCancel=aNotif;
     break;
  }
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel]
```

;

Comment: in a mothod and call when you want to delete the notification